# D3 cannot read property offsetHeight of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, null, offsetwidth, offsetheight

I get this `cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null` while i just initialized its height.

Here is my code:

```
d3.select("#container")
    .style("height", "100%")
    .style("width", "100%") 
    .style("position", "relative")
    .style("bottom", 0);


var width = document.getElementById("#container").offsetWidth,
    height = document.getElementById("#container").offsetHeight,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 1.5);
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `document.getElementById()` you don't have to explicitly type a `#` before the id.

Comment: I know, that doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: If the same error is thrown when using `document.getElementById("container")`, I'd check if it even returns anything. If not, the element either doesn't exist at all or the document isn't ready at the time of the code being executed.
By the error you're describing, my guess is that it isn't an issue with d3.js but with the last three lines.